# Iterating the values in my object

Tags: php

I have an object which holds a 2 dimensional array but I can't seem to get the output working.

I look the data like this:

```
foreach($myObj as $key){
    foreach($myObj[$key] as $key2){
        echo '['.$key.','.$key2.'], ';
    }
}
```

But i get no output just a blank page. I also have no error's in my error log.

My object is structured like this:

```
coOrds Object
(
    [xy:coOrds:private] => Array
        (
            [10] => Array //value 10 would be $key
                (
                    [10] => //10 here would be $key2
                    [11] => 
                    [12] => 
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [10] => 
                    [11] => 
                    [12] => 
                )

        )
}
```

What am i doing wrong for my loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach($myObj as $key => $array){
    foreach($array as $key2 => $array2){
        echo '['.$key.','.$key2.'], ';
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Since `xy` is private, you should either:

- make it public
- create a simple getter `public function getXY() { return $this->xy; }`

Then:

```
foreach($myObj->getXY() as $key => $array){
    foreach($array as $key2 => $array2){
        echo '['.$key.','.$key2.'], ';
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

A working sample:

```
class coOrds {
  public $xy = array(10 => array(1, 2, 3), 11 => array(4,5,6));
}

$myObj = new coOrds();

foreach($myObj->xy as $key => $array){
    foreach($array as $key2 => $array2){
        echo '['.$key.','.$key2.'], ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[10,0], [10,1], [10,2], [11,0], [11,1], [11,2],
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to loop at all i put echo 'test'; in the first foreach scope and it doesn't display..

Comment: @Dave What's `$myObj`? Is it an instance of `coOrds`? The structure you showed is a `var_dump` of `$myObj`?

Comment: `$myObj` with `print_r($myObj);` is what you see in the question :)

Comment: @Dave Then `xy` is a private property, in that case you would not be able to access it? Can you include the source code of your object?

Comment: You mean provide the class structure?

Comment: @Dave ok i edited. This might now work because it's untested but it's in the right direction.

Comment: Ok i set it to public and it works kind of, i get this out put `[xy,6], [xy,7], [xy,8], ` not sure why its giving me the string rather than the value =/

Comment: @Dave You might not call the right variable, I edited my answer to add a working example based on the information you given me.

Comment: Hmm i'll investigate it see why its happening ! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Dave You're welcome. And don't forget to enable error reporting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php), you seem to be missing crucial information for efficient debugging.